# No contexts were measured, what is the reason of this warning

Tags: python, coverage.py

I was generating coverage reports in html. Now I wanted to see which test ran the code, So added this change, .coveragerc file with

```
    [run]
    dynamic_context = test_function
```

and show context flag in command, coverage html -i --data-file=.coverage1 --show-contexts

After running the command I see this warning,

```
   /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/coverage/html.py:59: CoverageWarning: No contexts were measured
  self.coverage._warn("No contexts were measured")
```

An in report I see, 1ctx which is test_function but not the test which is executing the code.
[image]

What is the meaning of this warning. How to correct it. I tried placing the .coveragerc in tests folder, app folder and in root folder